# What kind of connectivity is used for android phone to act as a game controller?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I want to use an Android Phone as a game controller on a game played on an Android Tablet.

What is the best connection type for me to use?

Because I read some information:

> Bluetooth initial latency ~25-40ms

So, is it better to use Wifi or Wifi-Direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example you can look to http://ardrone2.parrot.com/ardrone-2/altitude/ they are using Android/iOS device as controller which connects through Wifi and have a nice result.

In general I think wifi is a better choice, also looking into this comparison http://www.diffen.com/difference/Bluetooth_vs_Wifi

Comment: Hi Van, this sounds very interessting. I think this is the information i've been looking for. Great thx